# navigator.notification.vibrate(milliseconds) not working

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I`m just starting to use Phonegap in combination with the phonegap appbuilder. Working just fine but I have an issue with navigator.notification.vibrate(milliseconds). I`m not getting my Samsung S4 & S3 to vibrate :-( . The beep and the alert are working fine but no vibration...

This is my sample code index.html:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);
    }

    // Show a custom alert
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    // Beep three times
    //
    function playBeep() {
        navigator.notification.beep(3);
        navigator.notification.vibrate(2500);
    }

    // Vibrate for 2 seconds
    //
    function vibrate() {
        navigator.notification.vibrate(2000);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="playBeep(); return false;">Play Beep</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="vibrate(); return false;">Vibrate</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.hello-world"
        version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>RTS Demo</name>

    <description>
        Demo
    </description>

    <author href="http://www.test.com" email="test@test.com">
        Sjaak Trekhaak
    </author>

    <!--
        Enable individual API permissions here.
        The "device" permission is required for the 'deviceready' event.
    -->
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

    <!--
        If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
        following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
        permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
    -->
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <gap:platform name="android" />

    <!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
    <preference name="phonegap-version"           value="2.9.0" />          <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="7" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration"     value="0"/>

    <!-- Plugins can also be added here. -->
    <!--
        <gap:plugin name="Example" />
        A list of available plugins are available at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins
    -->

    <!-- Define app icon for each platform. -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <!--
        Define access to external domains.

        <access />            - a blank access tag denies access to all external resources.
        <access origin="*" /> - a wildcard access tag allows access to all external resource.

        Otherwise, you can specify specific domains:
    -->
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <!--
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" />                    - allow any secure requests to http://phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" subdomains="true" />  - same as above, but including subdomains, such as http://build.phonegap.com/
        <access origin="http://phonegap.com" browserOnly="true" /> - only allows http://phonegap.com to be opened by the child browser.
    -->

</widget>
```

I`m not sure what is going wrong?

Kind Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the notification feature to your config.xml:

```
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
</feature>
```

If you're using appbuilder, that should do it. If you were building it yourself using Eclipse and the Android SDK you'd need to add permission to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: no luck.. really strange the alert and beep work (also without the feature option) but no vibration :((

Comment: Maybe it is my phone.. but i tried it on a Samsung S4 and S3 ... no luck :(

Comment: Assuming you're using Phonegap 3.x, make sure you've added the vibration plugin to your project: `phonegap plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-vibration.git`

Comment: mmm what do I need to download? the js file and add that to my index file? Is there any documentation on how to create a project that is suitable for the appbuilder? Why does the beep work and the vibrate not?

Comment: added: <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.vibration" /> to my config.xml ... now the vibration is working... but the other two are not....

Comment: Ok, I needed to add:
<preference name="phonegap-version"           value="3.0.0" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.vibration" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.dialogs" />

Now it is working! Thanks for your help Dpa99c!!!

Comment: `<uses-permission ... VIBRATE />`Worked for Android studio project with WebViewClient on a Android 6 phone.